# Share State Between MainWindow and UserControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have a WPF application and want to share data between my MainWindow and one or more UserConrols, but for simplicity lets assume I have only one MainWindow.xaml and one UserControl.xaml. From what I've gathered so far, this can be done with Bindings and Properties. So I tried this with no success.

The Object I want to share between the controls looks like this:

```
SharedObject {
 prop string Name;
 prop List<Product> Products;
}

Product {
 prop string ItemName;
 prop double Price;
 prop bool Available;
}
```

So I load the SharedData in the MainWindow and want to be able to edit this in the UserControl, but in TwoWay mode, to get the modified product list updates also in the MainWindow. I also want to access and modify the Name Property of the SharedObject in the UserControl.

How can I achieve this? Is the Property/Binding the way to go? Can this state management also be done in a more *elegant* way? (in dotnet Core 3.1)

Comment: Set the `DataContext` of the window to an instance of your view model (`SharedObject`) and then let the `UserControl` inherit the `DataContext` (which it does by default).

Comment: Thank you! Much easier than expected. Can I access this inherited DataContext also in the code of the UserControl? When I use DataContext.ToString(), I see that it is the right Type, but I can't access/set the properties via DataContext.Name since it is not recognised before I start the application.

Comment: I got it now. By using (DataContext as <NameOfYourType>).Name you can access and set the properties. In order to also trigger updates the <NameOfYourType> class needs to extend INotifyPropertyChanged and invoke the PropertyChangedEventHandler when a new property value is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `DataContext` of the window to an instance of your view model (`SharedObject`) and then let the `UserControl` inherit the `DataContext` from its parent window (which it does by default).

You can then bind directly to any public property of the view model from the an element in `UserControl`.